# Laravel nested route slug link

Tags: laravel, routes, slug

I want to do route slug and im using slugable structure. I use SeoServiceProvider when define links.

```
 foreach($categories as $category){

  $router->get($category['path'], 'App\Http\Controllers\User\CategoryController@index')
    ->defaults('category', $category['id'])
    ->name($category['path'])
    ->middleware('web');
};
```

this way the category structure works.

```
site.com/category
site.com/category/subcategory
site.com/category/subcategory/subsubcategory
```

I want to make the following structure

```
site.com/product
site.com/category/product
site.com/category/subcategory/product
site.com/category/subcategory/subsubcategory/product
```

I need to do for this nested loop, Is there an easy way to do this.

Comment: Your issue here is going to be if a product has the same slug as a subcategory.